# WPF loading spinner

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, spinner, loading

The goal is to display the information that the application is working. So I'm looking for an intelligent implementation sample of a loading spinner using WPF / MVVM.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I wrote this [user control](http://huydinhpham.blogspot.com/2011/07/wpf-loading-panel.html) which may help, it will display messages with a progress bar spinning to show it is currently loading something.

```
  <ctr:LoadingPanel x:Name="loadingPanel"
                    IsLoading="{Binding PanelLoading}"
                    Message="{Binding PanelMainMessage}"
                    SubMessage="{Binding PanelSubMessage}" 
                    ClosePanelCommand="{Binding PanelCloseCommand}" />
```

It has a couple of basic properties that you can bind to.

Comment: Hi,
If I want to change the spinner color from blue to white then? is it possible in this? Please let me know. thx

Comment: This is [another example](http://huydinhpham.blogspot.com/2013/06/mahapps-flyout-loading-panel.html).

Comment: I have no Idea how to use this can you provide some documentation ? How to add this to my project and later use it ?

Comment: Solution does not build in vs2017

Comment: Yeah looks like it's a little deprecated. Looks great! But doesn't seem to work now :(

Answer (score 122):

A very simple "plug and play" spinner could be one of the spinning icons from the [Font Awesome Wpf Package](https://github.com/charri/Font-Awesome-WPF) ([Spinning icons](https://github.com/charri/Font-Awesome-WPF/blob/master/README-WPF.md#spinning-icons)).

The usage is quite simple, just install the nuget package:

```
PM> Install-Package FontAwesome.WPF
```

Then add the reference to the namespace

```
xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/"
```

and use the ImageAwesome control. Set the Spin="True" property and select one of the "Spinner", "Refresh", "Cog" and "CircleOutlinedNotched" Icon. It's scalable and can be resized by setting width and height.

```
<Window x:Class="Example.FontAwesome.WPF.Single"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/"
    Title="Single" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid  Margin="20">
        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Refresh" Spin="True" Height="48" Width="48" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Easily the best option. So many uses for these icons.
Check out all the other icons you may want to use here (there are so many there's a search): http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Comment: Unfortunately, `FontAwesome.WPF` is not compatible with recent .NET versions, like .Net Core 3.x, or .NET 5 or above, as it only strictly a .NET Framework project. This makes this solution hard to use in modern projects.

Comment: FontAwesome.WPF works for me in WPF app based on .NET 6.

Comment: @thomasmartinsen does that include the latest 5.xx icons, or the ones from the package release date, circa January 2017?

Answer (score 110):

To get this:

[image]

Stick this in a user control:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="FilledColor" A="255" B="155" R="155" G="155"/>
    <Color x:Key="UnfilledColor" A="0" B="155" R="155" G="155"/>

    <Style x:Key="BusyAnimationStyle" TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#7F000000"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="Animation0" BeginTime="00:00:00.0" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>

                        <Storyboard x:Key="Animation1" BeginTime="00:00:00.2" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>

                        <Storyboard x:Key="Animation2" BeginTime="00:00:00.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>

                        <Storyboard x:Key="Animation3" BeginTime="00:00:00.6" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>

                        <Storyboard x:Key="Animation4" BeginTime="00:00:00.8" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>

                        <Storyboard x:Key="Animation5" BeginTime="00:00:01.0" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>

                        <Storyboard x:Key="Animation6" BeginTime="00:00:01.2" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>

                        <Storyboard x:Key="Animation7" BeginTime="00:00:01.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse7" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation0}" x:Name="Storyboard0" />
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation1}" x:Name="Storyboard1"/>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation2}" x:Name="Storyboard2"/>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation3}" x:Name="Storyboard3"/>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation4}" x:Name="Storyboard4"/>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation5}" x:Name="Storyboard5"/>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation6}" x:Name="Storyboard6"/>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation7}" x:Name="Storyboard7"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>

                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard0"/>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard1"/>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard2"/>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard3"/>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard4"/>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard5"/>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard6"/>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard7"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                        <Canvas Height="60" Width="60">
                            <Canvas.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="15"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="15" />
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#009B9B9B" />
                                </Style>
                            </Canvas.Resources>

                            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse0" Canvas.Left="1.75" Canvas.Top="21"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse1" Canvas.Top="7" Canvas.Left="6.5"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse2" Canvas.Left="20.5" Canvas.Top="0.75"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse3" Canvas.Left="34.75" Canvas.Top="6.75"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse4" Canvas.Left="40.5" Canvas.Top="20.75" />
                            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse5" Canvas.Left="34.75" Canvas.Top="34.5"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse6" Canvas.Left="20.75" Canvas.Top="39.75"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse7" Canvas.Top="34.25" Canvas.Left="7" />
                            <Ellipse Width="39.5" Height="39.5" Canvas.Left="8.75" Canvas.Top="8" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                        </Canvas>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Control Style="{StaticResource BusyAnimationStyle}"/>
```

To get a cool disappearing effect on each ellipse add the following after each `ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames` element. Be sure to point it to the correct ellipse..

```
<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
</ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" >
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="15" />
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="00:00:01.0" Value="12" />
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="0" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" >
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="15" />
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="00:00:01.0" Value="12" />
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="0" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Comment: wellp 4 years later this saved me a bunch of time and effort. Thanks

Comment: I added a GIF so people can see what this looks like before going further.

Comment: This is great. How do I make the background transparent so it overlays just the animation over my usercontrol instead of covering the whole usercontrol?

Comment: How can I modify the Ellipses so I can use this in different sizes? I want to shrink it down to 20x20

Comment: I updated @HAdes code (updated code posted below) to allow parameterised height, width, and ellipse size. It should automatically calculate necessary angles to suit the height and width.

Comment: How can I put a label on the right side of the spinner saying something like "Loading..."?

Comment: How can I make visible or not depending on a view model property bound to visibility property of the control?

Comment: For transparency just change `<Setter Property="Background" Value="#7F000000"/>` to `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>`. -- Visibility binding just works out of the box.  Just bind visibility to a proper value (e.g. I do it using a ValueConverter).  Nothing fancy needed there, it just works. :-)

Comment: Is there any way to make it so that the user control does not completely cover up the rest of the contents? Even when the background's Value is set to "Transparent", it still covers up the other controls.

Comment: On systems without GPU, I'm seeing very high CPU usage for this, is there any way around to address it?

Answer (score 58):

## With Images

Visual summary of options for spinning icons. Recorded using [Screen To Gif](https://github.com/NickeManarin/ScreenToGif).

---

#### Font-Awesome-WPF

[Documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/charri/Font-Awesome-WPF/blob/master/README-WPF.md#spinning-icons).

Install via NuGet:

> PM> Install-Package FontAwesome.WPF

Looks like this:

[image]

XAML:

```xml
<fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Spinner" Spin="True" SpinDuration="4" />
```

Icons pictured are `Spinner`, `CircleOutlineNotch`, `Refresh` and `Cog`. There are [many others](https://github.com/charri/Font-Awesome-WPF/blob/master/src/WPF/FontAwesome.WPF/FontAwesomeIcon.cs).

---

#### [Method from @HAdes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6369137/24874)

XAML copy/paste.

[image]

Comment: How can we use this in code ? how to call this image spinner from code @Drew Noakes

Comment: RE: FontAwesome. As of Nov 2020, the link above will have you install a package that doesn't work anymore. The correct link is https://github.com/MartinTopfstedt/FontAwesome5 and you need to install the "FontAwesome5" NuGet package (not FontAswesome5.WPF).

Comment: @SafeerMP did you manage to figure out how to use this in the code?

Answer (score 38):

In WPF, you can now simply do:

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait; // set the cursor to loading spinner

Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow; // set the cursor back to arrow
```

Comment: i know its been a few years, but simple, straight forward, and already supported by the framework +1

Comment: This saved me a heap of time. Part of the framework and implementable directly from code. My preferred solution.

Comment: I can't belive the solution was this easy, I was dreading the others. This is so simple and users can't just ignore it, like with so many others.

Comment: Thanks guys! I should have been answering questions for the last 5 years but forgot about this Stack Overflow account

Comment: Wow, I haven't seen the wait cursor for ages now. As far as I remember it was windows 7 wait cursor so it must've been back then when windows 7 was still in business. Good ol' times though. Looks like now it's not a good practice to let a user just wait idly in favor of full responsiveness and async operations since there's always something to do with your ui, even if it's just a jumping dinosaur.

Comment: This is a simple and clean solution BUT as the name implies this property is for _overriding_ the default cursor, so when done with the wait cursor it should not be replaced with another override but reset to `null`, otherwise you will loose default behaviours such as switching to IBeam when hovering a field, etc.
The doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouse.overridecursor

Answer (score 27):

You can do it without any additional controls and libraries, using only Image control and transform:

```
<Image
    Source="/images/spinner.png"
    Width="100"
    Height="100"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" Visibility="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="noFreeze" />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
    <Image.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                        To="360" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

Replace `/images/spinner.png` with your image. Change `To="360"` to `To="-360"` if you want to rotate it counterclockwise. `Duration="0:0:1"` equals to 1 second per rotation.

Comment: simply amazing solution!

Comment: Sorry. I know its an old answer, but I get an error: Exception: Cannot find resource named 'BooleanToVisibilityConverter'. Resource names are case sensitive. How can fix it?

Comment: @Gabms Define the static resource or remove the visibility attribute altogether.

Answer (score 10):

This is an update to the code given by @HAdes to parameterize width, height, and ellipse size.

This implementation automatically calculates required angles, widths, and heights on the fly.

The user control is bound to itself (code-behind) which takes care of all calculations.

**XAML**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.Spinner"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="FilledColor" A="255" B="155" R="155" G="155"/>
        <Color x:Key="UnfilledColor" A="0" B="155" R="155" G="155"/>

        <Style x:Key="BusyAnimationStyle" TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="Animation0" BeginTime="00:00:00.0" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipseN" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>

                            <Storyboard x:Key="Animation1" BeginTime="00:00:00.2" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipseNE" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>

                            <Storyboard x:Key="Animation2" BeginTime="00:00:00.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipseE" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>

                            <Storyboard x:Key="Animation3" BeginTime="00:00:00.6" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipseSE" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>

                            <Storyboard x:Key="Animation4" BeginTime="00:00:00.8" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipseS" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>

                            <Storyboard x:Key="Animation5" BeginTime="00:00:01.0" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipseSW" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>

                            <Storyboard x:Key="Animation6" BeginTime="00:00:01.2" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipseW" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>

                            <Storyboard x:Key="Animation7" BeginTime="00:00:01.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipseNW" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="{StaticResource FilledColor}"/>
                                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="{StaticResource UnfilledColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation0}" x:Name="Storyboard0" />
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation1}" x:Name="Storyboard1"/>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation2}" x:Name="Storyboard2"/>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation3}" x:Name="Storyboard3"/>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation4}" x:Name="Storyboard4"/>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation5}" x:Name="Storyboard5"/>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation6}" x:Name="Storyboard6"/>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation7}" x:Name="Storyboard7"/>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>

                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard0"/>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard1"/>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard2"/>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard3"/>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard4"/>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard5"/>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard6"/>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard7"/>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Canvas>
                                    <Canvas.Resources>
                                        <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=EllipseSize}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=EllipseSize}" />
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </Canvas.Resources>

                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipseN" Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=EllipseN.Left}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=EllipseN.Top}"/>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipseNE" Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=EllipseNE.Left}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=EllipseNE.Top}"/>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipseE" Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=EllipseE.Left}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=EllipseE.Top}"/>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipseSE" Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=EllipseSE.Left}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=EllipseSE.Top}"/>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipseS" Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=EllipseS.Left}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=EllipseS.Top}"/>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipseSW" Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=EllipseSW.Left}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=EllipseSW.Top}"/>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipseW" Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=EllipseW.Left}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=EllipseW.Top}"/>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipseNW" Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=EllipseNW.Left}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=EllipseNW.Top}"/>

                                </Canvas>
                                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Border>
        <Control Style="{StaticResource BusyAnimationStyle}"/>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

**Code Behind (C#)**

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Spinner.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Spinner : UserControl
    {
        public int EllipseSize { get; set; } = 8;
        public int SpinnerHeight { get; set; } = 0;
        public int SpinnerWidth { get; set; } = 0;


        // start positions
        public EllipseStartPosition EllipseN { get; private set; }
        public EllipseStartPosition EllipseNE { get; private set; }
        public EllipseStartPosition EllipseE { get; private set; }
        public EllipseStartPosition EllipseSE { get; private set; }
        public EllipseStartPosition EllipseS { get; private set; }
        public EllipseStartPosition EllipseSW { get; private set; }
        public EllipseStartPosition EllipseW { get; private set; }
        public EllipseStartPosition EllipseNW { get; private set; }

        public Spinner()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void initialSetup()
        {
            float horizontalCenter = (float)(SpinnerWidth / 2);
            float verticalCenter = (float)(SpinnerHeight / 2);
            float distance = (float)Math.Min(SpinnerHeight, SpinnerWidth) /2;

            double angleInRadians = 44.8;
            float cosine = (float)Math.Cos(angleInRadians);
            float sine = (float)Math.Sin(angleInRadians);

            EllipseN = newPos(left: horizontalCenter, top: verticalCenter - distance);
            EllipseNE = newPos(left: horizontalCenter + (distance * cosine), top: verticalCenter - (distance * sine));
            EllipseE = newPos(left: horizontalCenter + distance, top: verticalCenter);
            EllipseSE = newPos(left: horizontalCenter + (distance * cosine), top: verticalCenter + (distance * sine));
            EllipseS = newPos(left: horizontalCenter, top: verticalCenter + distance);
            EllipseSW = newPos(left: horizontalCenter - (distance * cosine), top: verticalCenter + (distance * sine));
            EllipseW = newPos(left: horizontalCenter - distance, top: verticalCenter);
            EllipseNW = newPos(left: horizontalCenter - (distance * cosine), top: verticalCenter - (distance * sine));
        }

        private EllipseStartPosition newPos(float left, float top)
        {
            return new EllipseStartPosition() { Left = left, Top = top };
        }

        
        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Property.Name == "Height")
            {
                SpinnerHeight = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewValue);
            }

            if (e.Property.Name == "Width")
            {
                SpinnerWidth = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewValue);
            }

            if(SpinnerHeight > 0 && SpinnerWidth > 0)
            {
                initialSetup();
            }

            base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        }
    }

    public struct EllipseStartPosition
    {
        public float Left { get; set; }
        public float Top { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Sample Use**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        xmlns:animated="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <StackPanel Background="DarkGoldenrod" Width="200" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <Button Height="35">
            <Button.Content >
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Height="NaN" Width="NaN" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <local:Spinner EllipseSize="4" DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,10,5" Height="16" Width="16"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Cancel" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>

    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Comment: Be sure to include **DataContext = this;** after **InitializeComponent();** so the bindings correctly work.

Comment: @ShawnRoser DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" line in xaml does that

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct.  When I copied the code from your example I started from the <UserControl.Resources> line.  I completely missed it when reviewing the xaml portion of the example.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of an all-xaml solution. It binds to an "IsWorking" boolean in the viewmodel to show the control and start the animation.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MainApp.Views.SpinnerView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5"
                     Visibility="{Binding IsWorking, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}">
        <Label>Wait...</Label>
        <Ellipse x:Name="spinnerEllipse" 
                     Width="20" Height="20">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,1" EndPoint="0,0" >
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="CornflowerBlue" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="SpinnerRotate" CenterX="10" CenterY="10"/>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <Ellipse.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWorking}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="SpinStoryboard">
                                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" >
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:01"
                                            RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="SpinStoryboard"></StopStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Ellipse.Style>
        </Ellipse>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Looks interesting, but I was not able to let it work

Comment: An example solution is available at: https://iseghelp.blob.core.windows.net/examples/Spinner.zip.

Comment: Note that the closing </UserControl> tag is not displayed in the code snippet above.

Comment: I tried to edit your post to add the closing </UserControl>, but with no luck. Thanks for the example solution: not exactly what I was looking for but nice stuff anyway (I'm trying to learn something about XAML's graphics). Have a nice day.

Comment: Hope it helped. Good reference book for animations, etc: "WPF 4.5 Unleashed" by Adam Nathan.

Answer (score 3):

This repo on github seems to do the job quite well:

https://github.com/blackspikeltd/Xaml-Spinners-WPF

The spinners are all light weight and can easily be placed wherever needed. There is a sample project included in the repo that shows how to use them.

No nasty code-behinds with a bunch of logic either. If MVVM support is needed, one can just take these and throw them in a Grid with a Visibility binding.

Answer (score 2):

use an enum type to indicate your ViewModel's State

```
public enum ViewModeType
{
    Default, 
    Busy
    //etc.
}
```

then in your ViewModels Base class use a property

```
public ViewModeType ViewMode
{
    get { return this.viewMode; }
    set
    {
        if (this.viewMode != value)
        {
            this.viewMode = value;
                            //You should notify property changed here
        }
    }
}
```

and in view trigger the ViewMode and if it is busy show busyindicator:

```
<Trigger Property="ViewMode" Value="Busy">
    <!-- Show BusyIndicator -->
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 1):

The customized spinner posted by @Menol had a small issue where the spinner would be shifted down and to the right by the size of one dot. I have updated the code so that it compensates for this offset by subtracting by half the dot.

Here is the updated code:

```
    private void initialSetup()
    {
        float horizontalCenter = (float)(SpinnerWidth / 2);
        float verticalCenter = (float)(SpinnerHeight / 2);
        float distance = (float)Math.Min(SpinnerHeight, SpinnerWidth) / 2;
        float dotComp = (float)(EllipseSize / 2);

        double angleInRadians = 44.8;
        float cosine = (float)Math.Cos(angleInRadians);
        float sine = (float)Math.Sin(angleInRadians);

        EllipseN = newPos(left: horizontalCenter - dotComp, top: verticalCenter - distance - dotComp);
        EllipseNE = newPos(left: horizontalCenter + (distance * cosine) - dotComp, top: verticalCenter - (distance * sine) - dotComp);
        EllipseE = newPos(left: horizontalCenter + distance - dotComp, top: verticalCenter - dotComp);
        EllipseSE = newPos(left: horizontalCenter + (distance * cosine) - dotComp, top: verticalCenter + (distance * sine) - dotComp);
        EllipseS = newPos(left: horizontalCenter - dotComp, top: verticalCenter + distance - dotComp);
        EllipseSW = newPos(left: horizontalCenter - (distance * cosine) - dotComp, top: verticalCenter + (distance * sine) - dotComp);
        EllipseW = newPos(left: horizontalCenter - distance - dotComp, top: verticalCenter - dotComp);
        EllipseNW = newPos(left: horizontalCenter - (distance * cosine) - dotComp, top: verticalCenter - (distance * sine) - dotComp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

CircularProgressBarBlue.xaml

```
<UserControl 
x:Class="CircularProgressBarBlue"   
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Background="Transparent"
Name="progressBar">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="spinning" >
        <DoubleAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="SpinnerRotate" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RotateTransform.Angle)"                 
            From="0" 
            To="360"                 
            RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid 
    x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
    Background="Transparent" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Image Source="C:\SpinnerImage\BlueSpinner.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform 
                x:Name="SpinnerRotate"
                Angle="0"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>


</Grid>
```

CircularProgressBarBlue.xaml.cs

```
using System;

using System.Windows;

using System.Windows.Media.Animation;


        /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CircularProgressBarBlue.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CircularProgressBarBlue
    {
        private Storyboard _sb;

        public CircularProgressBarBlue()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StartStoryBoard();
            IsVisibleChanged += CircularProgressBarBlueIsVisibleChanged;
        }

        void CircularProgressBarBlueIsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_sb == null) return;
            if (e != null && e.NewValue != null && (((bool)e.NewValue)))
            {
                _sb.Begin();
                _sb.Resume();
            }
            else
            {
                _sb.Stop();
            }
        }

        void StartStoryBoard()
        {
            try
            {
                _sb = (Storyboard)TryFindResource("spinning");
                if (_sb != null)
                    _sb.Begin();
            }
            catch
            { }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach is to use geometry with animations applied. Add the required geometry to the **Path** and animate its **RotateTransform** from 0-360°.

My spinner support two types of spinners:

1. Circles :  [image] [image]
2. Rings :  [image] [image]

And the central logic looks like:

```
if(spinner.SpinnerType == SpinnerType.Ring)
{
 double innerRad = spinner.Radius - spinner.ItemRadius;
 Point center = new Point(0, 0);
 grp.Children.Add(new EllipseGeometry( center, spinner.Radius, spinner.Radius));
 grp.Children.Add(new EllipseGeometry(center, innerRad, innerRad));                
 return;
}
var points = GetPointsOnCircle( spinner.Diameter/ 2);
double r = spinner.ItemRadius;
foreach (var point in points)
{
 grp.Children.Add(new EllipseGeometry(point, r, r));
 r -= spinner.ContinuousSizeReduction;
}
```

Usage is as simple as follows:

`<local:SpinnerControl Diameter="60" Fill="#FFE8B311"/>`

[Here](http://www.wikiupload.com/HHZFN1YE2XBJUVR) is the source code!

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid Width="100" Height="100">
<Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="4">
    <Ellipse.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="rotateTransform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                        From="0" To="360"
                        Duration="0:0:1"
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Ellipse.Triggers>
    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" CenterX="10" CenterY="10"/>
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
</Ellipse>
```

In this example, an Ellipse with a Stroke of "Gray" and a StrokeThickness of "4" is used to create the ring shape. The RenderTransform property is used to rotate the Ellipse using a RotateTransform object, and the animation is triggered by the Loaded event of the FrameworkElement. The Duration of the DoubleAnimation is set to "0:0:1", meaning the rotation will take 1 second to complete. The RepeatBehavior is set to "Forever", so the animation will repeat indefinitely.

Other spiner with Square shape:

```
<Grid Width="100" Height="100">
<Path Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="4" StrokeEndLineCap="Round">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="50,10">
                <LineSegment Point="10,50" />
                <LineSegment Point="50,90" />
                <LineSegment Point="90,50" />
                <LineSegment Point="50,10" />
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
    <Path.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="rotateTransform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                        From="0" To="360"
                        Duration="0:0:1"
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Path.Triggers>
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" />
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll add my solution as well because it does not require any external resources like images and can be scaled indefinately without losing quality because it uses a path.
You can bind the paths.IsEnabled to the property that indicates if the spinner shall spin or not. The speed can be adjusted using the duration property:

the result:

[image] [image]

the XAML:

```
<Path Width="30" Height="30" Stretch="Fill" Fill="Black" Data="M20,12A8,8 0 0,1 12,20A8,8 0 0,1 4,12A8,8 0 0,1 12,4C12.76,4 13.5,4.11 14.2,4.31L15.77,2.74C14.61,2.26 13.34,2 12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
<!--
Use this if you prefer the dots instead of the open circle
<Path Stretch="Fill" Fill="Black" Data="M12 19C13.1 19 14 19.9 14 21S13.1 23 12 23 10 22.1 10 21 10.9 19 12 19M12 1C13.1 1 14 1.9 14 3S13.1 5 12 5 10 4.1 10 3 10.9 1 12 1M6 16C7.1 16 8 16.9 8 18S7.1 20 6 20 4 19.1 4 18 4.9 16 6 16M3 10C4.1 10 5 10.9 5 12S4.1 14 3 14 1 13.1 1 12 1.9 10 3 10M6 4C7.1 4 8 4.9 8 6S7.1 8 6 8 4 7.1 4 6 4.9 4 6 4M18 16C19.1 16 20 16.9 20 18S19.1 20 18 20 16 19.1 16 18 16.9 16 18 16M21 10C22.1 10 23 10.9 23 12S22.1 14 21 14 19 13.1 19 12 19.9 10 21 10M18 4C19.1 4 20 4.9 20 6S19.1 8 18 8 16 7.1 16 6 16.9 4 18 4Z" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
-->
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform/>
    </Path.RenderTransform>

    <Path.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Image.IsEnabled" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
From="0"
To="360"
Duration="0:0:1"
RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Path.Style>
</Path>
```