# WPF Icon to spin

Tags: wpf, xaml, font-awesome

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39595927/10705051) answer i have two questions:

> 1. Whats the name of the marked icon?

[image]

> 2. How can I make it to raotate to the other direction, i.e to spin like:

[image]

Itried to add `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"` like:

```
<fa:ImageAwesome FlowDirection="RightToLeft" SpinDuration="6" Icon="Cog" Width="200" Height="200" Foreground="White" Spin="True" />
```

but it still rotate to same direction

Comment: Kudos for mspaint arrows

Comment: Why don't you simply draw a `Path`-`Arc` and rotate it with an `Animation`?

Comment: `CircleOutlineNotch` is the name of the icon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should do the trick for you:

[image]

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <Viewbox Height="30" Width="30" Stretch="Fill">
        <Path Stretch="Fill" Fill="Black" Data="M20,12A8,8 0 0,1 12,20A8,8 0 0,1 4,12A8,8 0 0,1 12,4C12.76,4 13.5,4.11 14.2,4.31L15.77,2.74C14.61,2.26 13.34,2 12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>

            <Path.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Image.IsEnabled" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
        From="0"
        To="360"
        Duration="0:0:1"
        RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Path.Style>
        </Path>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: How do you know that that's the `Data`, it there any tool for that?, I mean how did you come up with: `Data="M28,2.202v4.059C37.053......"`

Comment: Suppuse I want it thicker, or bigger

Comment: i guess in this case you need to try to understand what is achtually happening and modify it to your needs.
 You can modify its size by changing the height of the viewbox
<Viewbox Height="20">

Comment: You can checkout incscape it can convert bitmap images to Vector images and XAML files to create an icon. If that is to much digging for your right now you can replace the path with an image and put your icon there as image