Load another thread with a Page to prevent UI freezing while rendering stuff in WPF
I'm new in WPF and C#, I have this problem where I have a loading spinner and a button that loads new Pages inside a frame.
What I want is to render the spinner on top of the Frame, and load the Page on another thread (the page contains a data grid with a lot of data that makes the UI freeze), so the spinner can spin without freezing and then disappear when the Page finishes rendering all items on the data grid.
I have this so far:
private void StackPanel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadingSpinner.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    var ClickedButton = e.Source as UserControls.MenuButton;
    if (ClickedButton.Command != NavigationCommands.BrowseBack && ClickedButton.NavUri != null)
    {
        Page page = (Page)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(ClickedButton.NavUri.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
        page.DataContext = DataContext;
        pgContenedorConfiguracion.NavigationService.Navigate(page);
    }

    LoadingSpinner.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

There are two issues with this code:

The spinner instantly disappear.
If I remove LoadingSpinner.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; the spinner starts freeze and then, when the page finishes rendering, it starts to spin.

Then I came up with this code:
private void StackPanel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    LoadingSpinner.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    var ClickedButton = e.Source as UserControls.MenuButton;
    if (ClickedButton.Command != NavigationCommands.BrowseBack && ClickedButton.NavUri != null)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        {
            Page page = (Page)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(ClickedButton.NavUri.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
            page.DataContext = DataContext;
            pgContenedorConfiguracion.NavigationService.Navigate(page);
        }));
    }

    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(() =>
    {
        LoadingSpinner.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }));
}

It kind of works, now the spinner appears at the beginning without disappearing instantly, but its freeze, and somehow it disappear after the page is rendered… can someone explain to me what is going on here? I understand that dispatcher makes priorities, but no more than that.
Is there any best way to do what I want?

Whenever you use Dispatcher.Invoke in WPF you're sending stuff to be done in the UI/Main thread, which is the only thread that can interact with the UI. Giving it a background priority might change the order in which the UI thread does stuff, but everything is still happening syncronously on the UI thread. To do things asynchronously while showing a spinner a better idea would be to invoke an AsyncCommand from your ViewModel. A more hacky way to do it that also works is to just fire and forget a task with Task.Run in your event handler.

@Janilson Alright I understand your comment and thanks for the reply, but when I wrap the code in task.run (it was previously wrapped inside dispatcher background) it gives me an error that says "the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it", and the error points me to a dependency property defined inside MenuButton, which is a user control...

Why do you think you need a new thread for drawing the UI? In WPF, threads (or Tasks) are used for fetching data or doing long computations. Unless you're doing something daft, like drawing a million points on a graphical plot, the UI rendering should take minimal time.

@Peregrine I'm not looking exactly for a new thread actually, that is what comes to my mind, because the datagrid takes about 3 seconds to load, and the UI is frozen during that time, for that reason I would like a loading screen... If you have a better idea on how to do this without a frozen spinner let me know D; Thanks for the reply!

That error happens because you can't change UI objects outside the UI thread. So for example. changing the visibility of the loading spinner needs to happen either on the event handler or in a Dispatcher Invoke call. However actions that don't touch the UI can happen in any thread. I'm assuming that if your datagrid takes 3 seconds to open you're probably getting the data from a large file or from a web api call, these IO actions are the type of thing that should happen in a separate thread.

Is the new page your own code or third party?   if it is your own, you could likely identify code-paths invoked at load-time inside that page which could be made asynchronous.  For example, if it is loading some data from a file or a database, make that an asynchronous task launched at loading but one that loading does not wait for.

Already tons of similar questions here on SO, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359848/wpf-loading-spinner

You can't load the Page on a different thread as Page is a DispatcherObject and as such has thread affinity.
What you want to do is to load the data and perform the initialization on a different thread or asynchronously.
Navigating using objects should be avoided when possible as this will impact performance. WPF navigation controls hold a history to enable backward and forward navigation. If you navigate with objects, the controls will keep the complete objects in memory. But if you navigate by URI, the memory footprint is significantly lower (loading may take longer due to the instantiation).
If you want to reuse Page instances in the navigation host to improve loading times if necessary, then you should also store the reference in your navigator class instead of creating new instances each time.
Either navigate by URI or store a reference to the reused Page instance.
To disable the busy spinner you must wait for the initialization to complete. Otherwise, you will hide it prematurely. I suggest listening to an event for this purpose.
Additionally, Page provides a NavigationService instance that is linked to the parent navigation host. You don't need any references to the navigation host in your pages. This will only lead to bad design decisions.
From a design perspective, you should consider adding the busy indicator to the Page so that the Page can fully control itself how to render content and when to show placeholders and busy indicators. This way external classes don't have to care about such details of other classes internal state.
private readonly myPage = new MyPage();
private bool isNavigationCompleted;

private void ShowSpinner()
  => LoadingSpinner.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

private void HideSpinner()
  => LoadingSpinner.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

private void StackPanel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ShowSpinner();

  var clickedButton = e.Source as UserControls.MenuButton;
  if (clickedButton.Command != NavigationCommands.BrowseBack 
    && clickedButton.NavUri != null)
  {
    // Get notified when the navigation to the page being completed 
    // (Page is created but not loaded at this point).
    // Hide the busy indicator if page has also completed initialization.
    this.NavigationService.LoadCompleted += OnPageLoadCompleted;

    // Get notified when the page has completed initialization.
    // Hide the busy indicator if the page navigation has also completed.
    this.myPage.InitializationCompleted += OnPageInitializationCompleted;
    
    // Don't create new instance on each call
    //Page page = (Page)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(ClickedButton.NavUri.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));

    // DataContext is inherited. The following line is redundant.
    //page.DataContext = DataContext;

    this.isNavigationCompleted = false;

    // Instead, reuse the page instance
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(this.myPage);
  }
}

private void OnPageLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  this.isNavigationCompleted = true;
  this.NavigationService.LoadCompleted -= OnPageLoadCompleted;

  var myPage = (MyPage)e.Content;  
  if (myPage.IsInitialized)
  {
    HideSpinner();
  }
}

private void OnPageInitializationCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  var myPage = (MyPage)sender;  
  myPage.InitializationCompleted -= OnPageInitializationCompleted;

  if (this.isNavigationCompleted)
  {
    HideSpinner();
  }
}

A good pattern for asynchronous or concurrent initialization in the view is letting the control implement an InitializeAsync method that you then call from the Loaded event:
partial class MyPage : Page
{
  public event EventHandler InitializationCompleted;
  public bool IsInitialized { get; private set; }

  public MyPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    this.IsInitialized = false;
  }

  private async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => await InitializeAsnyc();

  private async Task InitializeAsnyc()
  {
    if (this.IsInitialized)
    {
      return;
    }

    // Preferably call async APIs
    await GetDataAsymc();

    // You can offload long running and CPU intensive work 
    // to a background thread.
    // If not awaited, the context immediately continues while the Task.Run operation 
    // executes in the background
    await Task.Run(DoSomethingInTheBackground);

    // TODO::Finalize initialization


    this.IsInitialized = true;
    OnInitializationCompleted();
  }

  // The CPU intensive and long running operation
  private void DoSomethingInTheBackground()
  {
  }

  protected virtual void OnInitializationCompleted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => this.InitializationCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}


Hello, thanks for the reply. I finally managed to get it working, actually not by your response, but you gave me a really good hint on how to approach my goal, I also found a way of doing it based on another post. I'm going to respond myself with the solution. Thanks!

I have improved the code to eliminate the race condition between page loading and initialization. i also fixed a bug where the event handler was added instead of removed (copy&paste error).

What I'm about to write in this answer is not a good practice, but it works...
Sometimes it's really difficult to make things that appear to be easy in WPF, but you encounter so many problems while coding and those problems doesn't make much sense (At least for beginners).
The main issue here is that the UI thread gets saturated by rendering controls in the window or page, even if you do asynchronous functions to retrieve data from anywhere, it will always freeze for a short period of seconds, I managed to reduce my time from 3 seconds to 0.5 (doing async functions for data) and most importantly I managed to put a loading spinner that doesn't freeze.
The way I did it was by creating a new Window with the spinner on it and creating a new thread with it. (I used to have the spinner on a user control, but now I don't)
To clarify, creating threads and then ending them several times, can make your application crash, but my code doesn't. I wanted to make sure that it will not crash, I have tested it for at least an hour, so you can trust this (If you find a bug let me know), also I'm not a senior developer on C#, SO if you can improve this code also let everyone knows.
using JPT_POS_Escritorio.Vista;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace JPT_POS_Escritorio.Helper
{
    internal class NavigationClass
    {
        string previousPage; // String with the name of the previous page (So you don't start the spinner on the same page).
        public NavigationClass(string previousPage = "" ) // When instantiate, pass previousPage argument.
        {
            this.previousPage = previousPage;
        }

        private LoadingScreen loadingScreen; // The window with the spinner.

        private bool shouldStopThread = false;
        private Thread newWindowThread; 

        public async Task navigationService(Page page, Frame frameContainer = null, int delay = 50) // This async function will navigate to the page asked.
        {
            if (previousPage != page.DependencyObjectType.Name)
            {
                StartThreadLoading(); // The thread starts.

                frameContainer.NavigationService.Navigate(page); // It navigates to the page.

                while (!page.IsLoaded) // This is not very elegant, but it works fine.
                    await Task.Delay(delay); // This will wait until the page is fully loaded.

                CloseWindowSafe(); // Once the page was loaded, it will close the window and thread safely.

                previousPage = page.DependencyObjectType.Name; // The previous page now is the current page.
            }
        }


        private void StartThreadLoading() // Create thread function
        {
            newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadStartingPoint));
            newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
            newWindowThread.Start();
        }

        private void ThreadStartingPoint() // Instance of the loadingScreen window, replace with yours.
        {
            loadingScreen = new LoadingScreen();
            try
            {
                loadingScreen.ShowDialog();
                loadingScreen.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>
                loadingScreen.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

                while (!shouldStopThread)
                {
                    Dispatcher.Run();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) // In case of unexpected error, the window will close.
            {
                loadingScreen.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new ThreadStart(loadingScreen.Close));
                loadingScreen.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
            }
        }

        void CloseWindowSafe() // Close window function
        {
            if (loadingScreen != null) // If the instance of the window is null, then do nothing, if not close window and thread.
            {
                shouldStopThread = true; 

                if (loadingScreen.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                    loadingScreen.Close();
                else
                    loadingScreen.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new ThreadStart(loadingScreen.Close));

                newWindowThread.Join();
            }
        }

    }
}

Example code:
First I create an instance of the class:
NavigationClass nc = new NavigationClass("pgnConfOpciones");

And then do the work for passing the page and the frame when the button is clicked.
private async void StackPanel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var ClickedButton = e.Source as UserControls.MenuButton;
        if (ClickedButton.PageNavigation != null)
        {
            // Get the page by it's name
            string namePage = ClickedButton.PageNavigation.ToString();
            FieldInfo field = GetType().GetField(namePage, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            if (field != null)
            {
                System.Windows.Controls.Page page = (System.Windows.Controls.Page)field.GetValue(this);

                if (page != null)
                {
                    // Call the function with the page and the frame
                    await nc.navigationService(page, pgContenedorConfiguracion);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"The page '{namePage}' is null.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"The page '{namePage}' was not found", nameof(namePage));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        new SimpleModal(ex.Message, SimpleModal.MessageType.Error, SimpleModal.MessageButtons.Ok, "A unexpected interface error ocurred.").ShowDialog();
    }
}

I also don't create new instances every time I click on the buttons, thanks to @BionicCode answer, every Page is instantiated before clicking any button.
This works perfectly fine now. If you wonder, this doesn't have memory or CPU leaks, it runs smooth using 2% of CPU at most.


This is not very good code. the extra STA thread can and should be avoided. Then don't poll the page.IsLoaded property in a busy waiting loop. That's an anti-pattern. Instead handle the NavigationService.LoadCompleted event. The exception handling is also smelly as you shouldn't swallow exceptions. If the window crashes, then it crashes. If it crashes then this means a severe error has happened. You want to fix it. Let it crash and then debug your application to fix it.

Then don't use reflection to make a class access its own fields. If you have to lookup objects then use a Dictionary e.g. Dictionary<string, Page>.  The loop that repeatedly calls Dispatcher.Run is also wrong. A single call starts the dispatcher queue. The Thread.Join is also totally redundant. There is no need to synchronize threads. The loadingScreen.Dispatcher.CheckAccess is also redundant as it will never be true.

Your solution does not solve the original problem that the initialization of the page instance blocks the main thread. While your spinner is spinning in the new STA thread the main tread is still blocked and not able to process anything else, like user input etc. In other words, the application remains unresponsive.

Sorry if I sounded rude. I was just sharing my thoughts to give you feedback.

@BionicCode thanks for your feedback, that is exactly what I wanted, I wasn't sure if what I did was ok, atleast the spinner spins... Tomorrow I will correct my code and find other ways, as I mentioned i'm such a noob on c# :(. It would be good if you can make a tutorial about this topic for the love of art, there is not much information about how to handle this type of circumstances.
